# Laptop keyboard not detected, boots into startup repair

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, drivers

I was having issues with my Lenovo laptop's keyboard and had to uninstall its driver. After restarting the PC, the driver was automatically reinstalled, and I checked it from the device manager. Then I shut down the laptop.

But now it doesn't start and says the keyboard isn't detected then goes into Startup Repair. Automatic repair isn't working and its generated log file says:

> Root cause found: A recent driver installation or upgrade may be preventing the system from starting.

> Repair action: System files integrity check and repair.

> Result: Failed. Error code = 0x57

How do I fix this?

OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Shut down. Hold down the Shift Key, press the power button and start in Safe Mode.  Can you start in Safe Mode and repair the keyboard.

Comment: I really wish people wouldn’t uninstall the default Windows system USB driver.  How is doing that even a solution to any problem?  I have literally never seen it solve any problem, only cause problems, and a lot of headaches

Comment: Holding the shift key while starting the laptop isn't starting safe mode, it still goes into the Startup Repair screen after saying "Keyboard Not Detected"

Comment: Try starting with a USB key created from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Take care - Windows is not running so it may try to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Have you tried popping the laptop keyboard off and checking the cable connection? There should be plenty of videos on YouTube of how to do this safely to prevent damage.